# Establishing a WebSocket client connection in Jetty?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I'm following this tutorial to establish a WebSocket connection to a server: 
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html

The code (same as the tutorial):

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;

/**
 * Example of a simple Echo Client.
 */
public class SimpleEchoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String destUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            destUri = args[0];
        }
        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
        SimpleEchoClient socket = new SimpleEchoClient();

        try {
            client.start();
            URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
            System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n", echoUri);
           // socket.awaitClose(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                client.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Errors:

```
2014-08-07 21:49:00.346:INFO::main: Logging initialized @86ms
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.InvalidWebSocketException:
SimpleEchoClient is not a valid WebSocket object.  
Object must obey one of the following rules:  
(1) class implements org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketListener or  
(2) class is annotated with @org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket

at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.EventDriverFactory.wrap(EventDriverFactory.java:145)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient.connect(WebSocketClient.java:200)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient.connect(WebSocketClient.java:144)
at SimpleEchoClient.main(SimpleEchoClient.java:31)
```

I'm not too sure what is wrong with my imported jar file. Maybe it is the wrong one? I'm using this: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client/9.2.2.v20140723

Surely there must be an easier way to establish a connection via Jetty Websocket and start receiving data?

Comment: "SimpleEchoClient is not a valid WebSocket object. Object must obey one of the following rules: (1) class implements org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketListener or (2) class is annotated with @org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket"

Comment: Stupid question, how do I fix that?

Comment: Either implement `WebSocketListener` or use the `WebSocket` annotation. You've skipped basic Java, haven't you?

Comment: He cut and pasted verbatim from the docs.  The problem isn't the code it's the version of the lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kayman explained in the comment, your problem with the socket handler implementation, use the latest release here explained with an example(same you used but correct) http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation is out-of-date with the current version you are using.  Try rolling back to a more stable version of 9.2.x like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.0.RC0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is not a stable version of websocket-client, this is an early pre-release (RC0. aka Release Candidate 0).  Use something newer.  Such as `9.2.3.v20140905`